# Why does Pandas .loc achieve more hits than MultiIndex.intersection?

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have two dataframes, each with 49 layered multiindexes (made up of floats, strings, np.nan, etc) and I'm trying to find the intersection of those multindexes. My initial approach was:
`df3 = df1.loc[df2.index]`
Which gave me nearly 100% match rate, which was about what I was expecting. Using this method though, pandas was throwing a warning
*FutureWarning:
Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing label will raise
KeyError in the future, you can use .reindex() as an alternative.
See the documentation here:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#deprecate-loc-reindex-listlike*
So, following the suggestion in the documentation that best suited my purpose, I re-implemented my solution to:

`df3 = df1.loc[df1.index.intersection(df2.index)]`
However, this achieved less than 10% match rate.
I know that the intersection method is missing expected index matches. I validated this with the following
`df1.index[0] in df2.index[0:1] # returns true`
while
`df1.index[0:1].intersection(df2.index[0:1]) # returns empty`
How does .loc achieve the appropriate number of matches in nearly the equivalent time while intersection cannot? How can I replicate .loc's performance while still being future proof?

For context, I started with two datetime indexed dataframes with 49 common columns. The data in one of the dataframes is almost a subset of the data in the other (it may have some additional data). Also, the ordering of their indexes cannot be guaranteed to match. I am trying to use the datetime index of the subset dataframe as a reference time for the equivalent data row in the larger dataframe. The solution for this needs to be efficient too. I would appreciate any input on alternative approaches to this problem as well.

EDIT: I avoided using reindex because my index is duplicated, however I realised I could use it to find the index intersection as follows:

```
temp_df = df1[~df1.index.duplicated()].reindex(df2.index.drop_duplicates())
index_intersection = temp_df[temp_df.SomeColumn.notnull()].index
df3 = df1.loc[index_intersection]
```

Comment: Instead of `df1.loc[df2.index]`.  Use `df1.reindex(df2.index)`.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] ?

Comment: @AMC I have not been able to generate a minimal reproducible example yet